# Trouble converting "for key in dict" to == for exact matching

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, exact-match

Good morning,

I am having trouble pulling the correct value from my dictionary because there are similar keys. I believe I need to use the == instead of ***in*** however when I try to change `if key in c_item_number_one:` to `if key == c_item_number_one:` it just returns my `if not_found: print("Specify Size One")` however I know 12" is in the dictionary.

```
c_item_number_one = ('12", Pipe,, SA-106 GR. B,, SCH 40, WALL smls'.upper())
print(c_item_number_one)
My formula is as follows:

def item_one_size_one():
    not_found = True
    for key in size_one_dict:
        if key in c_item_number_one:
            item_number_one_size = size_one_dict[key]
            print(item_number_one_size)
            not_found = False
            break
    if not_found:
            print("Specify Size One")
item_one_size_one()
```

The current result is:

```
12", PIPE,, SA-106 GR. B,, SCH 40, WALL SMLS
Specify Size One
```

Comment: If you want the separate fields then you need to split the list on ','

Comment: Okay, so. What are the keys in `size_one_dict` currently? Which of them do you expect to match this string? According to what exact logic? I can't understand what you mean about "similar keys". When you tried the code using `in` rather than `==`, did something match that shouldn't? Please clarify.

Comment: @stark - Unfortunately the integer c_item_number_one will eventually be a user input and will not always have a comma seperating the values. It may be entered without any commas, with "-", blank spaces, or they may forget to separate a piece entirely. I'll work on solutions to those are a later point however right now I am just trying to understand how to adapt this function to pull exactly what is available.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - By similar keys I mean 2" and 12". It is pulling 2" when the correct size is 12".

Comment: Ah, then it is as @stark says.

Comment: You can give multiple delimiters to split, then try the field for exact match.  upper() is a good idea for the user input.

Comment: @stark - This does allow me to get the exact match of 12" however it causes a potential problem. Initially it didn't pull because I only have ```12"``` in my dictionary, not ```12",```. This means I would have to add a variation of every entry in my dictionary to include the potential of the different delimiters I've encountered in these item descriptions. Not that big of a deal as that's easy to concat however my dictionary is already 2500 key:value pairs long. When does that dictionary count become a problem?

Comment: @stark - Also, when I use the split method, it causes a different issue. The SCH 40 portion is another piece of info I need to extract (using a pretty identical function to the above for size) but by splitting it I can no longer grab that. I suppose I can refer to the unsplit string but then I go back to the original issue because I have keys in that dict such as SCH 10 and SCH 10S.

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two usages of the word `in` here - the first is in the context of a `for` loop, and the second entirely distinct one is in the context of a comparison.

In the construction of a for loop, the `in` keyword connects the variable that will be used to hold the values extracted from the loop to the object containing values to be looped over.

e.g.

```
for x in list:
```

Meanwhile, the entirely distinct usage of the `in` keyword can be used to tell python to perform a collection test where the left-hand side item is tested to see whether it exists in the rhs-object's collection.

e.g.

```
if key in c_item_number_one:
```

So the meaning of the `in` keyword is somewhat contextual.

If your code is giving unexpected results then you should be able to replace the if-statement to use an `==` test, while keeping everything else the same.

e.g.

```
if key == c_item_number_one:
```

<strike>However, since the contents of `c_item_number_one` is a tuple, you might only want to test equality for the first item in that tuple - the number 12 for example. You should do this by indexing the element in the tuple for which you want to do the comparison:</strike>

```
if key == c_item_number_one[0]:
```

Here the `[0]` is telling python to extract only the first element from the tuple to perform the `==` test.

[edit] Sorry, your c_item_number_one isn't a tuple, it's a long string. What you need is a way of clearly identifying each item to be looked up, using a unique code or value that the user can enter that will uniquely identify each thing. Doing a string-match like this is always going to throw up problems.

There's potential then for a bit of added nuance, the 1st key in your example tuple is a string of `'12'`. If the key in your `==` test is a numeric value of 12 (i.e. an integer) then the test `12 == '12'` will return false and you won't extract the value you're after. That your existing `in` test succeeds currently suggests though that this isn't a problem here, but might be something to be aware of later.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I entered the c_item_number_one as a string by using ' instead of " since I know it contains a " already. When I split that it still gives me ```['12",', 'PIPE,,', 'SA-106', 'GR.', 'B,,', 'SCH', '40,', 'WALL', 'SMLS']```

When I try to replace the if-statement as you suggest, it skips to my if not_found: value.

Comment: OK yes, I think I get it now - I'm guessing you want to do a kind of google-search type operation where the user enters one or more search terms, and the machine returns those items that give the best match, ideally picking the most likely one. Using the `==` means the user has to type the exact same string in its entirety, which for such a long, complex string is going to be tricky from a user perspective.Similarly, if you stick with 'in' then you'll get false matches where an input of `2` would return all items with `2`, `12`, or `back2back`. You need something inbetween these two extremes.

Comment: Question, in the code provided, what result would you want if the user entered `PIPE`?

Comment: Your edit to the solution is coming from the other direction for me. Let me provide a little more insight into what I am attempting to do. My customers provide us a list of items they want to buy. Unfortunately these item descriptions are written by people, which means they are short hand, so there are countless different ways to write the exact same thing. I also don't want to make the user do anything except copy and paste the descriptions into this and let the program do the heavy lifting. To be able to do this I plan on having a fair number of validation checks.

Comment: We use SAP and I created item codes for everything however I need to be able to generate the item code to enter it into excel. 

I created an excel workbook that generates our code and desired description by just index&match all the data I need however I have hit a bottleneck in excel with how much validation I can add to make sure the description isn't something that physically cannot exist. i.e. a shirt with truck wheels (not printed lol)

Comment: In excel, I had a similar issue to this in that it worked top-down so I had to arrange my data so any partial matches would be below the complete. i.e. highest to lowest. I like the idea of a dictionary because it allows for a much more fluid look-up.

Comment: If the user entered just PIPE then I would want this particular part of the code to generate PIPE.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I need to be able to generate the item code in order to be able to enter it into SAP, not excel..

Comment: Another possible approach might be to encode your search key with named key/value pairs, where the search terms are associated with some context. e.g. You might sell 'widgets', 'thingamabobs' and 'doobreys', but each of these comes in 2", 5", 12" versions. If you coded that as a string like this `type:widget size:2"` then at search time, you could ask the user to specify type and/or size, and you'd be able to search the text using the `in` operator for `size:2"` without worrying about clashes. It might get complicated, depending on the range of options.

Answer (score 1):

To split the user input into fields, use re.split

```
>>> userin
'12", PIPE,, SA-106 GR. B,, SCH 40, WALL SMLS'
>>> import re
>>> fields = re.split('[ ,]*',userin)
>>> fields
['12"', 'PIPE', 'SA-106', 'GR.', 'B', 'SCH', '40', 'WALL', 'SMLS']
```

Then compare the key to the first field, or to all fields:

```
if key == fields[0]:
```